# JAVA: Sorting duplicate values next to each other in a linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, user-defined-functions

so I'm trying to make a method that would position duplicate values next to each other. The method i did could do this but the problem is it sorts the list from low to high. Here is my function

> ```
>  private static void addValue(int val) {
>  
>          if (llist.size() == 0) {
>              llist.add(val);
>          } else if (llist.get(0) > val) {
>              llist.add(0, val);
>          } else if (llist.get(llist.size() - 1) < val) {
>              llist.add(llist.size(), val);
>          } else {
>              int i = 0;
>              while (llist.get(i) < val) {
>                  i++;
>              }
>              llist.add(i, val);
>          }
>  
>     }
> ```

My current output looks like this:
User input: 5

Linked list: [5,]

User input: 4

Linked list: [4,5]

User input: 3

Linked list: [3,4,5]

User input: 5

Linked list: [3,4,5,5]

User input: 3

Linked List: [3,3,4,5,5]

The output i want should be:

User input: 5

Linked list: [5,]

User input: 4

Linked list: [5,4]

User input: 3

Linked list: [5,4,3]

User input: 5

Linked list: [5,5,4,3]

User input: 3

Linked List: [5,5,4,3,3]

Comment: Suggest you have a look at [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) that does what you want without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Is `llist` a `java.util.LinkedList`?

Comment: @KevinAnderson yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
private static void addValue(int val) {
    int idx = llist.indexOf(val);
    if (idx == -1)
        llist.add(val);
    else
        llist.add(idx, val);
}
```

Basically, `llist.indexOf(val)` gives the index of the first item in `llist` that matches `val`, or -1 if there is no matching item.  So if there is already a matching item, we insert `val` at that location; otherwise, we add it at to the end.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you. I was already trying to learn about `public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) ` method but you saved me a great deal of time. Thank you!

Comment: You could actually do this with sorting, but you really wouldn't want to. It would be slower and a lot more complicated. Try it sometime, just for fun, and you'll see why. And do study up on `Collections.sort`; there will be plenty of other times when it truly is useful.